# Filter a list of offers by City that equal a value that i will enter it in my html

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm practicing some Angular/Ionic and am having a bit of a hard time figuring out how i get an offerLists filter by city,

this, is how i get all offres AllOffer.ts,
I get the offers across all users, I have to load all user data. like this:

```
export class AllOffresPage {

public offreList: Array<any>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
private db : AngularFireDatabase) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
let ref = firebase.database().ref("userProfile");
ref.on("value", userListSnapshot => {
  this.offreList = [];
  userListSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
    let offerListSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("offreList");

    offerListSnapshot.forEach(offerSnapshot => {
      this.offreList.push({
        id: offerSnapshot.key,
        titre: offerSnapshot.val().titre,
        sector: offerSnapshot.val().sector,
        city: offerSnapshot.val().city,
        descrip: offerSnapshot.val().descrip,
      });
      console.log(offerListSnapshot.key)
      return false;
    });
    })
   });
   }
```

Now the question is  how i get an offerLists filter by city,

```
 export class OffreByVillePage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
 }

 ionViewDidLoad() {

   // I don't know the code to show data filtered by city, I m stacking for 
    2 days
 }
```

Comment: Firebase has pretty good [documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), and there have been a lot of [questions on querying the database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+query). I recommend you spend some time on those, give it a try yourself, and post back with the concrete query code if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank's a lot Mr. Puffelen i will try